# hour must be between 0 and 23 -oracle

Tags: oracle, date, oracle12c

I just want to concatenate sysdate with string. i'm passing sysdate in **in_date** variable.  After executing the below query,

```
`select to_date('''||in_date||''' || '14:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

`
i'm getting error ***ORA-1850:hour must be between 0 and 23***

i'm using oracle 12c.

Thanks

Comment: See what `select '''||in_date||''' || '14:59:59' from dual` prints and you'll probably notice yourself what the problem is.

Comment: I think there is no space before time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer I assume the proper solution would be one of these:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '14:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM dual;

SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 14/24 + 59/24/60 + 59/24/60/60 FROM dual;
```

`SYSDATE` is a `DATE` value, you should **never** call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`. Implicitly Oracle is doing this:

```
SELECT 
 TO_DATE(''|| 
 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')) 
 ||'' || ' 14:59:59', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss')  
FROM dual;
```

So, the result depends on current user session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (and in your case also on `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`) which may change at any time.

Answer (score -1):

I've missed a space before time and also changes format 'yyyy' to 'yy'

```
select to_date(''||sysdate||'' || ' 14:59:59', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual;


27-04-2020 14:59:59
```

Thanks..

Comment: `SYSDATE` value is a `DATE` **NEVER** call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`